# Concat result of arithmetic operation with string

Tags: c#

I am new to c# and I'm learning about classes. Here is a piece of code I tried to write. I just wanna know how to subtract "Damage" from "Health", like this :
(look at the end)

```
public void Message()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Name + " Has received " + Damage + " Damage which makes his health " + Health - Damage);
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(Name + " Has received " + Damage + " Damage which makes his health " + (Health - Damage));` ?? Just prioritize the arithmetic operation..

Comment: You probably also want to actually subtract it: `Health -= Damage;`

Comment: Which is called **subtract and assign**..

Comment: also take a look at string.format

Comment: you need to change title of your question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you have here is with how the compiler compiles this expression, and this has to do with a topic called [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/).

Basically it sees this:

```
string + number - number
```

Unfortunately it combines the string with the number first and thus you get this:

```
string - number
```

Luckily the solution is simple, add parenthesis to get the compiler to evaluate the minus before the plus:

```
...his health " + (Health - Damage)
                  ^               ^
                  +-- add these --+
```

---

There are also other ways to write your statement so that this operator precedence doesn't come into play. You can use [`string.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Format_System_String_System_Object___):

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} Has received {1} Damage which makes his health {2}", Name, Damage, Health - Damage));
```

Some methods scattered around the .NET Framework even has support for this way of building a string built in, and `Console.WriteLine` is one of them, so you can even shorten the above to this:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} Has received {1} Damage which makes his health {2}", Name, Damage, Health - Damage);
```

Or you can do it with the newer syntax [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
Console.WriteLine($"{Name} Has received {Damage} Damage which makes his health {Health - Damage}");
```

Comment: What's with **String Interpolation**? Does it give additional boost in terms of performance or so?

Comment: String interpolation, in this case, gets compiled to the equivalent call to string.Format, the first such example from my answer, so no. I think, performance-wise, that none of the ways described in my answer has a significant edge over the others so go with what feels the most comfortable to you.

Comment: @RomeoSierra - probably nothing performance wise, but it's (arguably) easier to read and to modify. Imagine the above example, now you want to prepend something like `"{MonsterName} hit successfully"`. With string interpolation, that's easy. Without it, what do you do? Add the `MonsterName` as last argument and have the format string be `"{3} hit successfully. {0} Has received ..."`? Would look bad. And putting it as first argument, you would need to re-number the format string.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yup that's obvious.. I thought if it gives any performance boost or so. Afterall, strings are culprits that makes issues in terms of memory consumption and all.. Thanks for your tip.. :)

Answer (score 1):

While @Lasse gives the necessary modification as an answer, I would recommend using **Formatted Strings** instead.

```
string.Format("{0} Has received {1} Damage which makes his health {2}", Name, Damage, (Health - Damage));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can`t use classes as variable. You should create variables in your classes and operate on them(Create an instance of a class and on instance you will have all your variables and methods). Then you could easily do what you want.

Comment: @Doruk not there? 
"I am new to c# and I'm learning about classes"
I thought that he is using classes as a variable.

Comment: @RomeoSierra not there? "I am new to c# and I'm learning about classes" I thought that he is using classes as a variable.

Comment: @VladyslavHrehul Well.. It's *you thought*. :) You are looking at this problem in a different angle which is about **Conventions**. There is no hard and fast rule like *Class names should always be in Pascal Case*. That's a convention and a best practice. :) That's why your response is not making an answer..

Comment: @RomeoSierra in C# classes starts with upper character and variable with low. And this man told us that he is studying classes, so because I answered in this way.